# Input string was not in a correct format error #2

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following request:

```
   string sqlStr = @"Select a.Text, a.TrackKey, a.NoteType, a.TranKey, a.TranType, 
    Case a.TranType when '1110' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/SO/RMA/RMAView.asp?key=' 
     when '502' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/AR/InvInqDetail.asp?Key=' 
     when '511' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/AR/InvInqDetail.asp?Key=' 
     when '801' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/AR/OrdInqDetail.asp?Key='
     when '1101' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/AP/POInqDetail.asp?key=' 
     when '1111' then 'https://www.cps/SAM/PO/TruckDetail.asp?truckkey=' 
     when '835' then 'https://www.cpsm/SAM/SO/RMA/RMAView.asp?key='  End HREF, 
    Case when a.TranType = '1110' then 'M'
     when a.TranType = '502' then 'W'
     when a.TranType = '511' then 'W' 
     when a.TranType = '1101' then 'B'
     when a.TranType = '1111' then 'B'
     when a.TranType = '835' then '('  
     when (a.TranType = '801' and a.NoteType = '9') then '{'
     when (a.TranType = '801' and a.NoteType = '8') then '(' End dataicon      
    From tamTrackrEngine a 
    Where a.CreateDate > DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GetDate()), 0) 
    AND (a.EmpKey = {0} OR a.EmpKey IS NULL)
    AND a.Text IS NOT NULL
    Order by a.CreateDate DESC";

    var trackrinfo = db.Database.SqlQuery<TrackrData>(sqlStr, empKey).ToList();

    var TrackrInfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackrinfo);

    Response.Write(TrackrInfo);
    HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return new EmptyResult();
```

When I run this code I get the error:

> input string was not in a correct format.

I have put in a simpler sql query and gotten my results back without any problems so I think it has to do with some of the quotes in my query.

Here is my StackTrace:

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +10930058   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +63   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +790   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +208   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass63`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__62() +45   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +333   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass63`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__61() +140   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably(String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +335   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters) +61   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass13`1.<ExecuteSqlQuery>b__12() +151   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() +12   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58   SAM3.Controllers.SharedDataController.Trackr() in c:\Users\candicesteele\Source\Repos\SAM3\SAM3\Controllers\SharedDataController.cs:273   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c() +50   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e() +225   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e() +225   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19() +26   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 273 var trackrinfo = db.Database.SqlQuery(sqlStr, empKey).ToList();Line 274:Line 275:

Comment: Where are you getting the exception?

Comment: Is that the error line? If so it is the line of 
    var trackrinfo = db.Database.SqlQuery<TrackrData>(sqlStr, empKey).ToList()

Comment: What's the value of `empKey`?

Comment: It is a number. A working example would be 160.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's going to be problem with the internal format. It's calling `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` according to that stack trace. The problem is related to your `'{'` in the SQL statement.

This is completely testable just by using `StringBuilder`.

Below blows up with

> System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("'{' {0}", 1);
```

You can remedy this by doubling up the `{`

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("'{{' {0}", 1);
```

Works just fine.

`{{` should output only a single `{`. Doubling it up escapes it.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yea, could be better as just a code block even if the color may go awry. EDIT: Nevermind, there are no newlines =/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an environment to try this in, but from reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx), it looks like you've got the right idea:

> "You can include parameter place holders in the SQL query string and then supply parameter values as additional arguments."

However, the place-holder in your query appears to be incorrect.

Replace `{0}` with `@p0` in the `sqlStr` string and run it again.

Comment: Heh, was just about to post this after you linked the document.

Comment: I still get the same error. I have used parameters in the format of {0} in other queries in my controller and haven't had any problems with them.

Comment: @user2456259 Double check that `String.Format` is not being ran against those other queries. I have not seen `{#}` used in regards to SQL and SQL objects. This should work. You can also try and construct a `DbParameter` and name it whatever instead of `@p0`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: No problem Grant. As far as I can tell they are the same and I have used a query without the case statements with the parameter passed through as {0} without any problems.

Comment: If I remove the case statements from my query they run without problem.

Comment: @user2456259 Heh, for kicks. instead of `then '{'`, do `then '{{'`. I wonder if the internal format is complaining.

Comment: I also removed the case statements dealing with the hrefs and it worked so that is my problem.

Comment: The second case statement works but not the first dealing with the href.

Comment: I changed the case statement formatting and still no luck.

Comment: Looks like it was the character of '{'. I changed it to a different character and it fixed my problem. Could you explain what he is saying about what to include in there. Unfortunately I can't change that character as it ties back to a font and character.

Comment: Okay. Will do. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this part:

> a.EmpKey = {0}

It looks like you may have tried to build this query using string.format() at some point.  In any case, that doesn't look like valid SQL to me (an int wouldn't have {/}, and if those are part of the value you're comparing against, they should be in ''s.)

Comment: I run the code in my SQL Server Management Studio and don't get any errors so I think it somehow running into something when running it in C#.

Comment: Looks like it is for a `string.Format` since it is on `EmpKey` and an `empKey`variable is being passed into a method with that string.